# Paginated Scanning of AWS DynamoDB // must read the entire table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to find entries in a table and cannot use a *Query*. But I only need one matching database entry from the table.

My idea is to do a paginated *Scan* with a reasonable result size and apply a filter. Once I find an entry, I will not request any further page from the Scan.

My assumption is now, that the DynamoDB fetches the entries *lazily*, i.e. at the moment I stop requesting further pages, DynamoDB stops scanning on the table, and explicitly **does not scan then *entire* table.**

An example: My table is of 100MB size. It consists of 100 entries a 1MB. (AWS documentation states, that the DynamoDB scans in 1MB chunks.) I specify a `Limit` for the scan results of 1. When a match is now found in the 5ths chunk, the scan is cancelled, and only 5% (the first 5 entries) are read.

**Is that assumption correct?**

**How can I see, how may entries where read during the scan?**

Comment: Could you explain a bit about your data model and why you cannot use query? There may be a better method without using scan. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I will. Maybe there is a better solution. But in general, independently from a better solution, I am interested whether a scan can be cancelled/aborted or if it always scans the entire table. :)
Actually, I planned to post another question for that, since I find both question worthy to be answered.

Comment: Yes a scan retrieves a max of 1mb (note a max item size is 400k) and then it’s up to you to do another scan using `lastKeyEvaluated` to continue where you left off. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination

Comment: Actually, here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.ReadData.Scan.html is stated, that the entire table is read. I fear, this is an unlucky wording on AWS side?